# Custom binary for codesign in xcodebuild (handling timestamp service is unavailable)

Tags: xcode, code-signing, xcodebuild, codesign, xcode-tools

On one of our projects, we have flaky errors from the `codesign` binary with `timestamp service is unavailable` errors. The thing is that these errors are happening way too random and cannot be reproduced in isolation. I would say that about 5% of builds are failing for this reason. And this is a lot

While there are options with removing timestamp at all for dev builds (which we do), we're talking about release builds here.

I tried changing toolchain and/pr sdk copying, and putting my version of `codesign` there, but it seems that while other binaries are called from the custom toolchain directory,`codesign` still called from `/usr/bin/codesign`

So I was wondering - is there any way to change the binary that will be called for codesigning in `xcodebuild`?

P.S. I could potentially remove signing at all and sign only after project will be built, but since project is a bit complex, leaving this as the last resort

Comment: Ditto this problem, and I'm trying to reach the same goal: prevent flaky timestamp service issues from causing build failures. I haven't found a solution. I suspect Apple is trying to enforce that binaries are only signed with the SIP-protected codesign tool.